# how to include page in other page J2ee Spring MVC2

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I need to include page in other page on my project Spring J2ee,

the page whitch must be included has beans to be displayed...
anyone has idea please?

Comment: Please provide some samples of code you are working on

Answer (score 0):

using include directive

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/myDir/myPage.jsp" %>
```